# How to eliminate permissions on Google-Script code for button in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, user-permissions

I have a shared Google Sheet with edit access given to everyone at my institution. The sheet includes a button that clears some of the cells, effectively resetting the sheet.

When I use it, everything works fine. When others (who have edit access) use it, it gives them the following error: "A script attached to this document needs your permission to run."

Is there a way I can remove permissions for the google-script/button? I hope to send an edit-access email link to a distribution of several email addresses and want them all to be able to use the button.

Any help on removing permission requirements on the button would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: No, you can't let people execute code without having authorized it to execute as them. Configure an installed trigger if it can run as you, otherwise you cannot avoid getting their approval first. If it needs their approval, try using a menu function instead of a clickable image.

Comment: I'm very new to google scripts - can you elaborate on installing a trigger to run as me? Or what would be a menu function?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/custom-functions https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable